# How do i unset row result when str_split characters is not upto required

Tags: php, string, split, each, rows

In my mysql database table called `promo`, I have `msg`, `price` and `qty` in column `code` row in the column are as example

```
code | msg          |  price  | qty
180  | weallwinthem |  150    | 7
180  | yeswellhappy |  520    | 15
180  | wearerunning |  100    | 10
```

How do I unset a row result of `qty` if the required `msg` `str_split` is not upto `qty` required?

E:g2

if msg split is `we, al, lw, in, th, em` and `qty` is 7 unset `qty` to 6 
example3

`we, al, lw, in, th, em`  `qty` 6 i have tried:

```
$sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM promo WHERE code='180' LIMIT 1");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
    $msg = $row["msg"];
    $qty = $row["qty"];
    $disp = str_split($msg, 2);
    for($b = 0; $b < 2; $b++) {
        if(strlen($disp[$b]) != $qty) {
            unset($qty[$b]);
            $amt += ($row["price"] * $qty);
            $so = "uncompleted";

        } else {

            $so = "$disp[$b]";
            echo "','$so $amt";
        }
    }
```

thanks for reading and impact in my solutions

Comment: You're missing a closing bracket in your code.

Comment: So sorry for that @grumpycrouton cant find it any line specify the line or do you have any solution or idea for my problem?

Comment: Actually I have no idea what you are asking, I was just letting you know you had a syntax issue.

Comment: so you are saying that you 'll break the message on 2 characters each and then count all of the chunks if number is not matched with the qty then update the quantity column.
for example "we, al, lw, in, th, em" count is 6 while assigned value is 7 so replace 7 with 6
is that what u asking for?

Comment: @tousif-khan yes do you have better solutions to problem?

Comment: why not `UPDATE promo SET qty = ceil(LENGTH('msg')/2) WHERE code=180` ?

Comment: Am a little  comfuss with your code please which line can i apply it or give full edition of your code with my code thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if msg split is `we, al, lw, in, th, em` and `qty` is 7 unset qty to 6

As far as I understood from your second example:

We can write a function that "calculate" the right `Qty` according the the `msg`.

1. Split the message
2. Count the amount of spliced words
3. This should be the new Qty. (return it)

---

```
function getDesiredQtyBySplit($msg){
   $split = str_split($msg, 2);
   $count = count($split);
   return $count;
}
```

For each row will run this function, if the row's Qty is the desiredQty - no need to take any action, otherwise, we should update the row's Qty column.

```
$sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM promo WHERE code='180' LIMIT 1");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
    $msg = $row["msg"];
    $qty = $row["qty"];
    $desiredQty = getDesiredQtyBySplit($msg);
    if($desiredQty != $qty){
       //Using mysqli, UPDATE qty so it would be $desiredQty
       //Make sure that your condition (WHERE) related to this specific row. 
      //Usually there's a "Primary Key" (for instance: id) which is has a unique value.
    }
}
```

Comment: mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE promo SET qty=' ??' WHERE id=$id");
i dont really know what we be my updating value can you kindly give full coding example of your solution?

Comment: Yea i go id culumn oready but not just included in my topic code what your saying

Comment: So yea, you should use the WHERE id="$row['id']", but notice that the format of the query should be different since you should bind the values in the mysqli query.